# Search a value in Oracle VARRAY collection

Tags: oracle, collections, varray

I have an Oracle table that has a column of type VARRAY Oracle collection type.

```
create or replace
TYPE            FUSION_USER.FUSION_KEY_LIST AS VARRAY(20) OF VARCHAR2(80);

CREATE TABLE FUSION_QUEUE_AUDIT
  (
    "XML_ID"            NUMBER NOT NULL ENABLE,
    "XML_MESSAGE_TYPE"  NUMBER(4,0) NOT NULL ENABLE,
    "XML_MESSAGE"       SYS.XMLTYPE,
    "KEY_ID"            NUMBER,
    "KEY_LIST"          FUSION_USER.FUSION_KEY_LIST,
    "STATUS_IND"        VARCHAR2(1 BYTE) NOT NULL ENABLE
);
```

The data in KEY_LIST column is stored as:

```
FUSION_USER.FUSION_KEY_LIST(1600458446,N)
FUSION_USER.FUSION_KEY_LIST(1600488742,N)
FUSION_USER.FUSION_KEY_LIST(1600481496,N)
FUSION_USER.FUSION_KEY_LIST(1600473344,N)
```

How do I search for a value in this column?. The below queries throws an error:

```
select * from fusion_queue_audit where xml_message_type = 560 and create_date > (sysdate - 8/24) and INSTR(key_list,'1600103836') > 0;

OR

select * from fusion_queue_audit where xml_message_type = 560 and create_date > (sysdate - 8/24) and key_list like '%1600103836%';
```

Thanks in advance
R

Answer (score 1):

You can apply `table` to the collection to access and filter its content like

```
select * from fusion_queue_audit
where xml_message_type = 560
  and create_date > (sysdate - 8/24)
  and exists (
    select 1 from table(key_list) t1
    where t1.column_value like '%1600103836%'
  );
```

Check the test example on [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=3900a5d30761ef4af12f9591f37cc669)